# error in validation of php file extension when uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, file-extension

I am trying to validate the file when it is uploading, I am using the following code to achieve it, but I am not getting the desired output.
Even though I am uploading the allowed extension types, I am still getting the echo message "You cannot upload files of this type!". which means the If condition`if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed, true))` is not getting true, 
thanks in Advance for helping me,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty ($_FILES['file'])){
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize  = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType  = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed, true)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                if ($fileSize <8000) {
                    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);
                    header("location: player_home.php?uploadSucess");
                    echo "success";
                }else{
                    echo "your file is too big";
                }
            }else{
                echo "There was an Error uploading your file!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
    <span class="sml">Maximum size of <span>8.0MB</span> for a file.‏
    <br>
    Allowed Types : jpg, jpeg, png
    </span>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-top:15px;">Save</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: did you try echoing `$fileActualExt` right before the if-condition to see if it is really like one of the array-elements?

Comment: did you check if the uploaded file type is one of the valid ext of your code: ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')? because i check and test the code and it works here.

Comment: then your `$fileName` is empty.

Comment: well thats the problem. `isset ()` returns a boolean (true/false). so your `$file` is a boolean and therefore your `$file['name']` wont work. use `if (!empty ($_FILES['file'])) $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name']`

Comment: is your file-input in your form named `file`? like `<input type="file" name="file">`

Comment: i guess you need to add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: Is it bigger than 8K? That's the limit you set in your code.

Comment: yes, you check `if ($fileSize <8000)` which means that the file needs to be smaller than 8kB because $filesize is in Bytes.

Comment: @wayneOS what should be the value If I want a max file size less than 8.0 MB `$fileSize > ???;`

Comment: Well, it should be `$filesize < 80000 ` ....

Comment: well Bytes * 1024 are KBytes. KBytes * 1024 are MBytes. calculate it yourself ;)

Comment: I have tried this 80000 but still getting error; when i tried this Its sucessfully uploaded 800000 @paul Hgo

Comment: What's the file size of the file you're actually trying to upload?

Comment: its 1.57Mb @PauloHgo

Comment: @wayneOS Thanks a lot Sir, for your precious time and cooperation.

Comment: Only thing I can think of here is to echo the `$filesize` variable...

Answer (score 0):

You may be tripping with the `true` option in the `in_array()` method. Remove that and the condition should work.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you echo `$fileActualExt` just before your condition?

Comment: It's because of the note above from @wayneOS. Your form tag should look like the following: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`